# How to processing matrix(data frame) automatically in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have got a 41x41 similarity matrix(or data frame), just like below(I enclose a full version in the attachment):

```
     V1    V2      V3      V4      V5      V6
 V1   1    0.068   0.211   0.285   0.198   0.047
 V2  0.068   1     0.851   0.450   0.277   0.014
 V3  0.211  0.851     1    0.660   0.420   0.113
 V4  0.285  0.450  0.660      1    0.896   0.466
 V5  0.198  0.277  0.420    0.896    1     0.241
 V6  0.047  0.014  0.113    0.466   0.241     1
```

I want to build a recommend list for each vector(Vx), the most similar at the first place, the dissimilar at the last. So I think I need to extract two columns(or two rows), sort the values by decrease, and extract the column names.
However, when I tries to choose columns automatically, it doesn’t work.

```
ms<-readLines("E:/exp/ccsm.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
d = as.data.frame(ms)
for(dcol in 2:length(ms))
 {
   temp<-d[,c(1,dcol)]
   nlist<-temp[order(d[,dcol], decreasing=T)]
   lname<-nlist[,1]
 }
Show Traceback
Rerun with Debug
Error in `[.data.frame`(d, , c(1, dcol)) : undefined columns selected
```

It seems that variables couldn’t be the column/row numbers? But there may be a much larger similarity matrix need to be process. If it could not achieve by some sort of loop, it would be a disaster.
I wonder if you could give me some advice on solving this problem. I would be most grateful if you could reply at your earliest convenience. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your main problem is that you're not reading in your file correctly to a data.frame.

I saved your sample data into `ccsm.txt` in the pwd of my R session and then ran the following:

```
ms <- readLines('ccsm.txt',encoding='UTF-8');
ms;
## [1] "     V1    V2      V3      V4      V5      V6"
## [2] " V1   1    0.068   0.211   0.285   0.198   0.047"
## [3] " V2  0.068   1     0.851   0.450   0.277   0.014"
## [4] " V3  0.211  0.851     1    0.660   0.420   0.113"
## [5] " V4  0.285  0.450  0.660      1    0.896   0.466"
## [6] " V5  0.198  0.277  0.420    0.896    1     0.241"
## [7] " V6  0.047  0.014  0.113    0.466   0.241     1"
d <- as.data.frame(ms);
d;
##                                                 ms
## 1         V1    V2      V3      V4      V5      V6
## 2  V1   1    0.068   0.211   0.285   0.198   0.047
## 3  V2  0.068   1     0.851   0.450   0.277   0.014
## 4  V3  0.211  0.851     1    0.660   0.420   0.113
## 5  V4  0.285  0.450  0.660      1    0.896   0.466
## 6  V5  0.198  0.277  0.420    0.896    1     0.241
## 7   V6  0.047  0.014  0.113    0.466   0.241     1
names(d);
## [1] "ms"
dim(d);
## [1] 7 1
sapply(d,class);
##       ms
## "factor"
```

As you can see, your [`readLines()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html)/[`as.data.frame()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.data.frame.html) calls resulted in a 7 by 1 data.frame whose single column consists of a factor of the original lines of text from the file.

Instead, you need to use [`read.table()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) (and there are other options as well, such as [`fread()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf#page=27) from [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)):

```
d <- read.table('ccsm.txt');
d;
##       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
## V1 1.000 0.068 0.211 0.285 0.198 0.047
## V2 0.068 1.000 0.851 0.450 0.277 0.014
## V3 0.211 0.851 1.000 0.660 0.420 0.113
## V4 0.285 0.450 0.660 1.000 0.896 0.466
## V5 0.198 0.277 0.420 0.896 1.000 0.241
## V6 0.047 0.014 0.113 0.466 0.241 1.000
names(d);
## [1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6"
dim(d);
## [1] 6 6
sapply(d,class);
##        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6
## "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Unfortunately, your code still does not work:

```
for (dcol in 2:length(ms)) {
    temp <- d[,c(1,dcol)];
    nlist <- temp[order(d[,dcol],decreasing=T)];
    lname <- nlist[,1];
};
## Error in `[.data.frame`(temp, order(d[, dcol], decreasing = T)) :
##   undefined columns selected
```

There are two problems here. First, `ms` contains the raw lines of text from the file, which number 7, since the header line is included. But there are only 6 rows in the file. Thus `d[,c(1,dcol)]` would fail when `dcol` reaches 7.

But `dcol` never reaches 7, because in the first iteration `temp[order(d[,dcol],decreasing=T)]` fails. This is because `temp` is a data.frame, because it was assigned from a two-column slice of `d`. But you're indexing `temp` using a single argument, which indexes the underlying list, which has only two components. The return value of the `order()` call consists of integers 1 to 6 because it operated on a column of `d` (and there are 6 rows in `d`), and so the integers 3 to 6 are all out-of-range for the two-component list underlying the `temp` data.frame.

Here's how I would compute the required output:

```
apply(d,1,order,decreasing=T);
##      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
## [1,]  1  2  3  4  5  6
## [2,]  4  3  2  5  4  4
## [3,]  3  4  4  3  3  5
## [4,]  5  5  5  6  2  3
## [5,]  2  1  1  2  6  1
## [6,]  6  6  6  1  1  2
```

If you want the names of the recommended vectors, rather than indexes, you can do this:

```
apply(d,1,function(x) names(d)[order(x,decreasing=T)]);
##      V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
## [1,] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6"
## [2,] "V4" "V3" "V2" "V5" "V4" "V4"
## [3,] "V3" "V4" "V4" "V3" "V3" "V5"
## [4,] "V5" "V5" "V5" "V6" "V2" "V3"
## [5,] "V2" "V1" "V1" "V2" "V6" "V1"
## [6,] "V6" "V6" "V6" "V1" "V1" "V2"
```

And if you don't like that first row, because it necessarily will always rank the "self" vector highest, you can index it out with `...[-1,]`.

Comment: Nice catch.  Surprised no one discovered that for 9 hours

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
diag(mat) <- -99
mat2 <- t(apply(mat,2,function(x) rev(order(x))))[,-ncol(mat)]
#> mat2
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#V1    4    3    5    2    6
#V2    3    4    5    1    6
#V3    2    4    5    1    6
#V4    5    3    6    2    1
#V5    4    3    2    6    1
#V6    4    5    3    1    2
```

Here each row contains, in descending order from left to right, the index number of the columns which are most similar to the vector specified in the row name according to your similarity matrix. This is achieved by `sort()` in combination with `rev()`, which orders the entries from their largest to the lowest value. This sorting is applied to each column of the original matrix. The diagonal is set to `-99` to circumvent the trivial result that each vector is most similar to itself by setting the similarity of a vector with itself to an arbitrary negative constant. This procedure puts the index number of the row under consideration as the last entry. For this reason, the last entry is removed from matrix (there's no point in comparing a vector to itself). The matrix is transposed for convenience in order to display the similarity by row.

**data**

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text="V1    V2      V3      V4      V5      V6
 V1   1    0.068   0.211   0.285   0.198   0.047
 V2  0.068   1     0.851   0.450   0.277   0.014
 V3  0.211  0.851     1    0.660   0.420   0.113
 V4  0.285  0.450  0.660      1    0.896   0.466
 V5  0.198  0.277  0.420    0.896    1     0.241
 V6  0.047  0.014  0.113    0.466   0.241     1", header=T))
```